# Numbering tables with Chapter numbers

Tags: adobe-indesign

From what I understand, "chapter" variables increment only when used with multi-document and .indb files. If you work with a single document, it stays at "1".

What is the best solution to automatically increment Tables and Figures numbering following below structure?

**Chapter 1**

```
Table 1-1 (^1-^#)
Figure 1-1
Figure 1-2
```

**Chapter 2**

```
Table 2-1
Figure 2-1
```

My workaround is to use the Chapter list style and to apply unused levels (like 4 or 5) but it doesn't work when there is two different items (ie. Tables AND figures). They cannot have the same level

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Chapter":

- level: 1
- ^#

"Table":

- level: 2
- ^1-^#
- restart numbers at this level after: Any Previous level

"Figure":

- level: 3
- ^1-^#
- *"And the trick iiiiis:"* restart numbers at this level after: **1**

[image]

Would that work as you wish?

Comment: This is the correct answer.

Comment: Works like a charm! It is not very intuitive to know that the "restart numbers at this level after:" field can be edited with numbers. Thanks!

Comment: @supershivas Agreed! Definitely not intuitive... Anyway, glad you solved your issue ^^

Answer (score 2):

I would start with proper naming your source files. So every object placed in InDesign is named/labelled.
It helps a lot when working with multiple tables/"Hard science"/university level publishing.

Then in signature of table you just use it's name
 `Type > Text Variables > Insert Variable > Image Name`.
 Easy to locate object (in links palette) and anchor it in specific place in text if needed (or link object grouped with it's signature to mention in main body).

Then just apply paragraph styles for tables and figures and make TOC out of them.

Comment: Interesting alternative!